# AsyncTask v/s ThreadPoolExecutor for network request

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

I am working on a project where i need to hit a web service download the data which is JSON and will be represented in a list. And all the list items have there thumbnail url's which would be downloaded and displayed in the list item.

I have done the entire calling part with both a ThreadPoolExecutor and a AsyncTask.

But from a design perspective which is a better option out of:
1. ThreadPoolExecutor
2. AsyncTask

Few adv. of ThreadPoolExecutor:
1. User can define no. of concurrent threads that can be executed.
2. Cancelling all the request at once.

Few adv. of AsyncTask:
1. Internally it uses a ThreadPoolExecutor, however we cant define no. of threads that run simultaneously.
2. Cancelling a single request is easy.
3. Ability to attach and detach a task.
4. Updating the UI from doInBackground is simple.

I know more advantages of AsyncTask, however for a simple application like fetching data from a web service and later on fetching images.

Which would be more appropriate a AsyncTask or ThreadPoolExecutor? If you can provide a few reasons regarding your choice it would be helpful.

I have read a few article here on SO but none that compares the two. If there are any that i missed sorry for the trouble could you please post me the link for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I consider that AsyncTask is useful if you want to load thumbnail using a series "cascade-call": in the onPostExecute, you can start the next AsyncTask to download the next thumbnail.

But if you want to improve efficiency, I suggest using ThreadPoolExecutor. This is a sentence from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

> Thread pools address two different problems: they **usually provide
>   improved performance** when executing large numbers of asynchronous
>   tasks, **due to reduced per-task invocation overhead**, and they provide a
>   means of bounding and managing the resources, including threads,
>   consumed when executing a collection of tasks. Each ThreadPoolExecutor
>   also maintains some basic statistics, such as the number of completed
>   tasks.

In conclusion, ThreadPoolExecutor was probably designed for cases such as your; for this reason, I suggest you this class.

Comment: Could you please post the link as well where is it mentioned?

Comment: Sure, I forgot it... http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: do any one of you have idea what <b>large numbers of asynchronous tasks</b> implies, like is large number refering to 10-20 threads or 100-200 threads or in range of 1000?